# Dialog Widget- How to pop up clicked image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery-Dialog Widget. I want to show the clicked image in pop-up. But with my code, it could not be done as I'm using this widget first time. Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li id="child"><img src="images/child1/image.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<script>
$('li[id="child"]').dialog({autoOpen: false});
$('li[id="child"]').click(function() {
$('li[id="child"]').dialog("open");
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I need to open the dialog of same element which is being clicked

Comment: `$('li[id="child"]')` should just be `$("#child")`.

Comment: you just have to wrap your code within `doc ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8wshH/)

```
$(function(){
  $("body").append('<div id="dialog"/>')    
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    height:400, width:500, modal: true, autoOpen:false
  });
  $('#child > img').on('click', function() {
    $("#dialog").html($('<img />', {src:this.src}));
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: It works good. But when I close pop up window, the original image disappears from the page. How to make my image to remain in the page?

Comment: Could you help me check, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439414/html-click-image-pop-up

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#child > img').on('click', function() {
        $(this).dialog('open');
    });
    $('#child > img').dialog({autoOpen: false});
});
</script>
```