# html click image pop up

Tags: javascript, html

I want when I click the image then showing big size image for me, like this [demo](http://www.ablanxue.com/uploadfile/201307/13750754746653915/ablanxue/index.html).

This is my image code. And please make in one html file, because this is just a webview by html editor, so no js and css file, please.

```
<p>
    <img src="http://myServerName.com/assets/newsImage/纳吉.jpg" style="width:100%" />
</p>
```

UPDATE:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.layout img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
<div class="layout">
  <input type="checkbox" id="zoomCheck">
  <label for="zoomCheck">
   <img src="http://myServer.com/assets/newsImage/纳吉.jpg" style="width:100%" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: like a pop up? or just make the image bigger?

Comment: like apop up when I click then showing

Comment: @imanshu15 Please check this , I want to showing like this one http://www.ablanxue.com/uploadfile/201307/13750754746653915/ablanxue/index.html

Comment: I get it, Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: the case is you only have asked the question, you havent shown that you have tried. If you can please show us your Javascript code you got right now?

Comment: @imanshu15 I update my code in my question. check please

Comment: My one only have html side no css and js one. just a webview

Answer (score 1):

Try this method may hope it will work for you

```
 input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.layout img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}


<div class="layout">
  <input type="checkbox" id="zoomCheck">
  <label for="zoomCheck">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I just add it before my html code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2VUN6/  (JavaScript (jQuery 1.10.1) )

Comment: Sorry..I want to like this one ...http://www.ablanxue.com/uploadfile/201307/13750754746653915/ablanxue/index.html

Comment: How can I make it in html? becouse my project only one html page, no css

Comment: <style> 
 input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.layout img {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
</style> use style in html

Comment: I tried not working for me

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: use  jsfiddle and show me your snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163853/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-manoj-bhardwaj).